# Is there any iOS UITableView analog in OS X?

Tags: macos, uitableview, cocoa

I'm trying to find UITableView analog for OS X, but have no success. Maybe there is an external library? All I need is a ScrollView with cells that are customizable (NSView subclasses will be the best option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSTableView`. From Apple's documentation:

> An NSTableView object displays data for a set of related records, with rows representing individual records and columns representing the attributes of those records.

It has all of the features that you are looking for and is included in the core Cocoa library. It's very easy to use and nowadays table views are view-based by default when created with Interface Builder.